# Where is the class-prediction layer located in FCN (Semantic Segmentation)? And how does it work for per-pixel prediction?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

Recently, I read FCN paper carefully and remained with one unanswered-question of myself.

**Brief introduction :** FCN is a dense prediction that predicts each pixel belongs to which classes. In PASCAL case, it will be 21 classes (21 objects + 1 background). For prediction, older method is using FC-layer with 21 output nodes and pick the highest output as the class. This layer (class-prediction layer) is located **in the very end of the network** which outs the class as we as for calculating the loss function. Newer method, it can be replaced by 21 1x1-conv operations.

My question is, once I read the paper (especially chapter 4.1), it seems that the class-prediction layer is right after the coarse-output (fused-feature maps), then followed by up-sampling layer (See pic no 1 below). In this case, class-prediction layer is not in the very end of network. How can this work to predict each pixel class? In the beginning, I was thinking that class-prediction layer was in the very end of the network (See Pic no 2 below). Thus, per-pixel, it will have 21 1x1-conv operations for per-pixel class prediction. But, my mind changed after I read chapter 4.1 in the paper I paste below. What do you think about this?

Best,

Ardian.

Click link below to see attached images.

[image: Chapter 4.1 of FCN paper]

[image: Location of class-prediction layer?]